# Make a flag above 80th percentile in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a continous column and i need to create a binary flag. All the values which are above 80th percentile will get value as 1 and rest 0. How can I do in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle seems to have the [`percent_rank` window function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm) just for that:

```
select  case
        when percent_rank() over (order by col1) >= 0.8 then 1
        else 0
        end as flag
,       *
from    YourTable
```